# how to get the most accurate user speed on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS developing. Can please anyone tell me the most accurate way to get the user speed in iOS. CLLocation speed doesn't seem to be correct.

Here is my code to get the speed

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    var speed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()
    speed = (locationManager.location?.speed)!
    print("speed - ", speed * 3.6)
```

Comment: What accuracy have you set for location manager?

Comment: @Abizern **kCLLocationAccuracyBest**

Comment: Gps speed is the best you are going to get and it should be pretty good. What speed are you comparing against?  What are the environmental conditions (inner city/ high rise? Open highway? Suburban streets?) what `horizontalAccuracy` is reported?

Answer (score 0):

Moving speed calculated using 'CLLocation' won't be accurate since you need the location to be updated continuously which would take a lot of resources. Hence, `CLLocation` updates the location based on intervals.

If, for whatever reason, you want the speed to be updated continuously, you need to look into `Accelerometer` and `Gyroscope`. By using the values from both and with some data manipulation, you can get a more reasonable value for the current speed.

**NOTE**
Keep in mind that doing so will take a toll on your device's resources and is not the best approach.